# Justify $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$ for complex $a$ and zero real part

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, integration

(Reposted from [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940717/justifying-int-0-infty-e-ax2-mathrmdx-for-complex-values))

I have searched and failed to find a rigorous proof showing that
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$$
is true for  $\Re(a)=0$ and $\Im(a)\neq0$. For example, why does
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i}}
$$
and does one need to invoke contour integration to show this? Is it just a coincidence this happens to work? Or is the following technique valid:

Suppose $\Re (b)>0$ and $a$ is complex; then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\ \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{b\to0}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+ b)x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{b\to0}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a+b}}.
$$

Another example is
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-ix}\ \mathrm{d}x = i^{-s}\Gamma(s)
$$
which follows from
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-ax}\ \mathrm{d}x = a^{-s}\Gamma(s),
$$
but why is it that both of these are true? I fail to believe it is just a coincidence. Is there an explanation (not a calculation) that can justify these results?

Thank you.

Comment: Look up Fresnel integrals for an answer to your first question.

Comment: I am already familiar with the Fresnel integrals. I am looking for a reason as to why the Fresnel integrals can be evaluated the way I have done in the OP.

Comment: Write $\int_0^\infty = \int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty$.
The first part is easily seen to be a continuous function of $a \in \bf C$.
The second part does not converge absolutely, so integrate by parts
once or twice to get an equivalent integral that's absolutely convergent
(plus an elementary function coming from the end point $x=1$)
and that you can prove is a continuous function of $a$ in the closed
upper half-plane.  Finally undo the integration by parts 
and recombine the two integrals.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt a$?

Comment: [correction to my earlier comment: $a$  in the closed *right* half-plane . . .]

Comment: Sorry about being a bit off the cuff in my first comment - you had said that you hadn't seen a rigorous way of doing the Fresnel integrals, and that's of course something you already find on Wikipedia. Now, alternatively continuing the integral as a function of the parameter $a$ will work up to a point if you check for continuity, as Noam Elkies nicely demonstrates, but if you're too naive about this, you of course can get questionable statements such as $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{x^2 } dx = i\sqrt{\pi } $; or is that $-i\sqrt{\pi } $, cf. the very pertinent comment by dodd?